# Solar neutrino Spectrum - Why are there discrete energies for Be and pep?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, astrophysics, neutrinos, sun

What is the reason why some reactions give a continuum for the energy of the released neutrinos and others give only a discrete value ($\ ^7B$ and $pep$ )?

Thanks for your help. Please feel free to use the figures below.

---

[image: Solar neutrino spectrum]

---

[image: Nuclear reactions inside the Sun]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Discrete spectra like that are characteristic of final-states of exactly two particles. For two fixed masses and a fixed total energy there is only one way to divide the energy that also conserves momentum.

With three or more particle in the final state there is a whole family of solutions, which leads to the broad spectra seen for $pp$, $^8\mathrm{B}$ and $hep$.

---

Compare to the [original expectation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/181024/520) for [the energy spectrum of beta decay electrons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/210676/520), and [the proposal of (what became known as) the neutrino in the first place](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21814/dear-radioactive-ladies-and-gentlemen-letter-by-wolfgang-pauli).