# Solar neutrino spectrum: why are there two lines for beryllium?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, neutrinos, sun

I have a follow-up question to this one:

[Solar neutrino Spectrum - Why are there discrete energies for Be and pep?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/383115/solar-neutrino-spectrum-why-are-there-discrete-energies-for-be-and-pep)

I understand why the lines for $^{7}\text{Be}$ and $pep$ are discrete, but why do we have $\textit{two}$ of them in the case of $^{7}\text{Be}$?

Comment: Because there are two different reactions leading to two different products.

Comment: @JonCuster I know that the 860 keV line corresponds to the electron capture. What is the reaction responsible for the lower-energy line?

Comment: Check ENSDF for the 7Li energy levels. (Sorry, two energy levels, not totally separate reactions).

Comment: @JonCuster Ah, I see, so the lower-energy line corresponds to the production of 7Li in its first excited state?

Comment: The energy difference seems about right by eyeballing it.

Comment: @JonCuster Feel free to post it as an answer :)

Comment: That might be a while since I’m on mobile-only on travel. Feel free to self-answer!

Comment: @JonCuster I am not quite clear how atomic spectra Be, Li, etc. can be detected on earth, given that the protosphere of the sun is around 6000 K. Wouldn't the blackbody thermal radiation of the sun overwhelm all atomic spectra lines? How can blackbody radiation noise be filtered clearly from the observation records taken on the earth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the final state contains three particles, solar neutrinos exhibit a continuous spectrum; if it's only two products, the solar neutrino spectrum is a discrete line. That's just energy and momentum conservation. The reaction you point out is

$e^-+{}^7\mathrm{Be}\rightarrow {}^7\mathrm{Li}+\nu_e$

But the ${}^7\mathrm{Li}$ has an energy state that is accessible in this decay; from the iaea.org Live Chart of Nuclides:

[image]

The lowest 477keV energy state is accessible, so the de-excitation gamma from that may carry those 477keV away. Hence, two discrete neutrino energies are possible with either 0.86MeV or 0.38MeV.