# How do I estimate the endpoint energy for the proton?

Tags: neutrons, protons

How can I estimate the endpoint energy for the proton in the neutron beta decay?

Following [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/210676/46926), I can write the system of equation as:

$$p_e+p_p+p_\nu=0$$

$$m_n=E_p+E_e+E_\nu$$

Assuming that the neutrino has no mass and that it has $p_\nu=0$, I have:
$$m_n=E_e+E_p=E_p+m_e+T_e$$ where $T_e$ is the electron kinetic energy. Now how do I proceed? I cannot impose $T_e=\dfrac{p_e^2}{2m_e}$ since the electron is relativistic

Comment: A massless particle cannot be at rest.italways moves at light speed.

Comment: @my2cts that is correct. So I have to assume that $p_\nu=0$

Comment: The neutrino is not actually massless, just light enough relative the dominate energy terms in the problem to ignore its mass.

Comment: The full relativistic expression for kinetic energy is (in $c=1$ units):
$T = E - m =  \sqrt{m^2 + p^2} - m = (\gamma - 1) m$,
where $\gamma = [1 - (v/c)^2]^{-1/2}$ is the Lorentz factor. Both expressions are messy, but they can be approximated reasonably when the energy is large compared to the mass (which kinda the case here).