# origins of the beta-decay energy spectrum

Tags: radiation, neutrinos

I understand that when beta decay occurs in the nucleus, the reason that the emergent electrons possess a distribution of energies is that varying amounts of the total energy release in the reaction get shared with the neutrinos, which carry it off stealthily. Hence the distribution, which represents the energy theft by the neutrinos.

What is the physical mechanism behind the "sharing process" that furnishes the distribution? In other words, what physical process is at work in the reaction which kicks out the neutrino with a nonunique amount of energy (hence leaving both the recoiling nucleus and the electron with nonunique energies)- as opposed to other nuclear reactions where, for example, a gamma ray gets emitted, always with a certain very well-defined characteristic energy?

Comment: I'm going to  handwavy guess that it (the physical mechanism) is related to the linear combination of mass eigenstates present at the creation of the neutrino and contributing to the resulting oscillations.  I put this comment here to see if it is incorporated into any more informed answer that you receive.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123823/123208 Note that the (anti) neutrino's direction is random relative to the beta particle's, although (of course) total momentum is conserved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the spectrum of the $\beta$-decay continuous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123823/why-is-the-spectrum-of-the-beta-decay-continuous)

Comment: @rfl, yes it does, thanks for the link!